# Standard representation of a set in an infinite product of sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given measurable spaces $(E,\mathcal{E}_i)_{i \in I}$, in general the infinite product of $\sigma$-algebras $(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i \in I}$ is by definition the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets in the form $\prod\limits_{i}A_i$ for $A_i \in \mathcal{E}$ where only in a finite set of indices $A_i \neq E$.

A general element of such sigma algebra can be described in some canonical way? If not, is that why we always use to verify properties on the generators (for example using monotone class theorem)?
Moreover how can we explicitly understand what the projection does on the siga algebras $\pi_S: \mathcal{E}^{\bigotimes I}\to\mathcal{E}^{\bigotimes S}$ where $S \subset I$ ?

Comment: I would rather say that $A_i$ must be in $\mathcal E_i$. Also, basis sets for the product $\sigma$-algebra are commonly called as [cylinder sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_%CF%83-algebra). I don't see how a general element can be described though, definitely it does not have to be cylindrical.

Comment: Yeah that is its not cylindrical is obvious and hence the question. I also suspect that there is anything canonical to think about this sets and why we always work with "on the generators argument" (and you are right it was a typo on my side)

Comment: No, in fact, even with simple sets like a single interval, the Borel sigma-field is already not describable with a formula using union, intersection and difference, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for the insight

Comment: Another mind-bending fact: if $E=  \{0,1\},$ then $E^\mathbf{N}$ with its product sigma-field is essentially $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma-algebra (think of binary expansion). You can therefore start with very nice factors and end up with a undescribable sigma field.